# WPF MVVM error when relating View and ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am learning to create an MVVM application following this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159939/Command-Binding-inside-DataTemplate-in-Parent-Chil), and it has this in its entrance view:

**what worked in the example**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductViewModel}">
        <vw:ProductView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SingleBrandViewModel}">
        <vw:SingleBrandView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

so i tried the following in my code

**what didn't work in my code**

```
<Page x:Class="MvvmAttempt.FilesView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmAttempt"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="FilesView">

    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:MySizeConverter x:Key="sizeConverter"/>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SingleFileView}">  <--- error here
                <local:SingleFileViewModel/>   <--- error here
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    ... other stuff ...
</Page>
```

`x:Type` has an underlining error message: `The type 'x:Type' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.`

under `<local:SingleFileViewModel/>` , the error is: `The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected: "DependencyObject".`

What could be causing the errors? Why did it expect `DependencyObject` when there isn't anything alike in the example code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your mistake sits here:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SingleFileView}">  <--- error here
    <local:SingleFileViewModel/>   <--- error here
</DataTemplate>
```

Note, that you have specified ViewModel as the DataTemplate, and the View as the DataType of DataTemplate. So it seems to me that this should work:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SingleFileViewModel}">
    <local:SingleFileView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks! now the `x:Type` line still complains, but it compiles fine. so guess i'll just ignore it...